# Inequality in Sobolev spaces that allows to prove weak differentiability

Tags: sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $f \in L^2([0,1])$.

Assume that for every $\varphi \in W^{1,2}([0,1])$ we know that
$$
\int_{0}^1 \varphi'(x) f(x) dx \leq \|\varphi \|_{W^{1,2}}. 
$$
Does this imply that $f$ belongs to $W^{1,2}([0,1])$?

My guess is yes because we can define $f'$ as
$$
 \int_0^1 \varphi(x) f'(x) dx  = - \int_0^1 \varphi'(x) f(x) dx, 
$$
but I am not able to formalize this idea.
Any hint is welcome, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the following function $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 1/2 \\ 1 &x \ge 1/2
\end{cases}
$$
You can easily check that $f \in L^2$.

Moreover, for all $\varphi$
$$\int_0^1 \varphi'(x) f(x) \ \mathrm dx \le \int_0^1 | \varphi'(x) | \cdot 1 \ \mathrm dx \le ||\varphi||_{W^{1,2}}$$
However $f$ is a step function: it has no weak derivative.

Comment: There should be an absolute value to make the first inequality true. More generally, the inequality $\int \phi'(x) f(x)\,dx\leq \|\phi\|_{W^{1,2}}$ holds whenever $\|f\|_2\leq 1$ by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

In order to define a function $g \in L^2$ via the formula
$$\int_0^1 \phi \, g \, \mathrm d x = \int_0^1 \phi' \, f \, \mathrm{d}x$$
you need
$$\int_0^1 \phi' \, f \, \mathrm{d} x \le C \, \|\phi\|_{L^2}.$$
In this case, the right-hand side of the first formula is defined on $W^{1,2}$ and is continuous w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm. Since $W^{1,2}$ is dense in $L^2$, it extends uniquely to a continuous functional on $L^2$. By the Riesz representation theorem, this can be identified with an $L^2$-function $g$.